# fit the background to any screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css

my page structure is like this:

```
<div id="maincontent">
   <div id="wrapper">
      <section id="first">

        <div id="slide1_header">
    <!--i have a background image here that should have to be fit in any screen 
           mostly(tablet and android device not required) but desktop or laptop screen size is required to be fit like somebody has the screen with 800px 1024px 1333px or ...
  widths            --> 
            <div id="logo"><a href="#" ><h1>Macras</h1></a></div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li id="slide1"><div >&nbsp;</div><span>Design website</span></li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li id="slide2"><div >&nbsp;</div><span>Graphic design</span></li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li id="slide3"><div >&nbsp;</div><span> porfolio</span></li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li id="slide4"><div >&nbsp;</div><span>cost</span></li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li id="slide5"><div >&nbsp;</div><span>order</span></li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li id="slide6"><div >&nbsp;</div><span>Contact us</span></li></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="slide1_body">

            <ul>
                <a href="#"><li><h2>Consult with our special consular</h2></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h2>get cost</h2></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h2> Design</h2></li></a>
            </ul>   
        </div>
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

my css code is like here but the problem that i have is that the background size is not fit to screen because i set the section to 1024px so should i use the percentage or there is a special technique for this problem.

css code:

```
#mainContent
{
    max-width:2048px;

    margin:0 auto;

}

#wrapper
{

    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;

}
#first
{
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    height:1000px;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}
#slide1_header
{
    width: 100%;
    height:180px;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
}
#logo
{
    margin-top:20px;
    background:url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat;
    height:140px;
    width:20%;
    float:right;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#logo h1
{
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
nav{oveflow:hidden; margin:20px auto; width:90%; }
nav ul li
{
    display:inline-block;
    height:110px;
    width:10%;
    margin-left:3px;

    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #efefef;
}

nav ul li div
{
    width:61px;
    height:60px;

    margin:10px auto;
}

nav ul li span
{
    color:#adadad;
    text-shadow:1px 1px white;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-right:30px;
}
#slide1 div
{
    background:url("../images/desingweb_icon.png") no-repeat; 
}
#slide2 div
{
    background:url("../images/graphicDesign_icon.png") no-repeat;
}
#slide3 div
{
    background:url("../images/nemoneh_icon.png") no-repeat;
}
#slide4 div
{
    background:url("../images/tarefeh_icon.png") no-repeat;
}
#slide5 div
{
    background:url("../images/hesab_icon.png") no-repeat;
}
#slide6 div
{
    background: url("../images/about_icon.png") no-repeat;
}
#slide1:hover{  background-color:#d3292a;}
#slide1:hover span{color:white; text-shadow:1px 1px grey;}
#slide2:hover{background-color:#1486ba;}
#slide2:hover span{color:white; text-shadow:1px 1px grey;}
#slide3:hover {background-color:#74a50d;}
#slide3:hover span{color:white;text-shadow:1px 1px grey; }
#slide4:hover{background-color:#ebebeb;}
#slide4:hover span{color:white;text-shadow:1px 1px grey; }
#slide5:hover{background-color:#2b2b2b;}
#slide5:hover span{color:white;text-shadow:1px 1px grey; }
#slide6:hover{background-color:#f7a900;}
#slide6:hover span{color:white;text-shadow:1px 1px grey; }

#slide1_body
{
    background:url("../images/design_bg.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:750px;

}
#slide1_body ul
{
    /*position:relative;
    top:408px;
    right:68.3%;*/
    padding-top:385px;
    padding-left:240px;
        width:12%;

}
#slide1_body ul li
{
background-color:#828282;

    color:#d9d9d9;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10% 10%;
    margin-top:3%;
    height:40px;
    width:145px;

}
#slide1_body ul li h2{
padding-top:10px;
}
#slide1_body ul li:hover
{
    background-color:#d02626;
    color:#fbf9f9;

}
```

In addition, I have different section that has different background image with different wrapper background color.

---

I am using the background-size property before but the problem is that it is not fit to all screen because I set the section to 1024px.

Comment: there is confusion in your question.
if you want to resize the background according to screen size then you give your background-size in percentage.
if you want to size all your sections according to screen size onload, use jquery.
or make your image of high resolution which will able to cover all screen size you thinking. That will sure cut your image, but will not create problem for you

Answer (score 1):

> Try this, maybe answer of what you searching for.

1. first method: It will simply scale the image all or the background but not supported by older browser.

   .class{
    background-size: cover !important;
    /* Below is for IE 8 or less */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='link-to-image-with-http', sizingMethod='scale');

   }
2. second method: Make your image of high resolution and apply this, rest scroll bar will take care.

   .class-img {
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
   }

> [Check this link](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size: cover` to stretch the background to fit.

[**More information**](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: yes i read this link before but it is not solved my problem. as i mention for Nathan Lee my problem is section tag. i edited my post again please read it again. thank u for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `background-size` css property to get what you are looking for.

For Instance,

```
.yourclass {
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your quickly response. i did it before but the problem  is my section it is set to 1024px. so it would be fit with 1024px right. i just edited my post please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery-backstretch](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch)